# SQL lag function avoid getting first row as null

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a sql query

```
    SELECT VALUE, LAG(VALUE,1,null) over(order by LOAD_DATE asc) as PREV_VALUE 
FROM TABLE LOAD_DATE >some_date

LOAD_DATE | VALUE
20210625    25
20210626    27
20210627    null
20210628    29
```

if my filter date is > 20210625 , I get value as 27 and previous value as null , is it possible to get the prev_value 25. If there is no filter I will get it. But filter is required to prevent reading the whole table. Also one more requirement. If previous value is null for example , date - 20210628, I should be getting previous non-null value that is 27.

Comment: Oracle or SQL server? They are different DBMSes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to calculate the last known value from the table and use it as a default value in LAG:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (LOAD_DATE DATE, [VALUE] INT);

INSERT INTO @Test (LOAD_DATE, [VALUE])
VALUES
        ('2021-06-25', 25)
    ,   ('2021-06-26', 27)
    ,   ('2021-06-27', null)
    ,   ('2021-06-28', 29)
;

DECLARE @LoadDate DATE = '2021-06-24';

WITH LastValue AS (
    SELECT
        MAX([VALUE]) AS [VALUE] /* This is to make sure, there is at least one record returned (e.g. the date is earlier than the first record in the table. */
    FROM
        (
            SELECT TOP(1)
                [VALUE]
            FROM
                @Test
            WHERE
                LOAD_DATE <= @LoadDate
            ORDER BY
                LOAD_DATE DESC
        ) X
)
SELECT
        T.*
    ,   LAG(T.VALUE, 1, LV.[VALUE]) OVER (ORDER BY T.LOAD_DATE) AS PREV_VALUE
FROM
    @Test T
    CROSS JOIN LastValue LV
WHERE
    T.LOAD_DATE > @LoadDate
;
```

Comment: Thank you very much . This approach worked. Also one more thing, if the value in previous date is null, I would like to fetch last non-null values.. (Last value ignore nulls doen't seem to be working in SQL server) Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Leo Think about it, the solution is easy, I would start to take a look at the inner query of the CTE, a condition might help there ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*, LAG(VALUE) OVER (ORDER BY LOAD_DATE) as PREV_VALUE
      FROM TABLE t
     ) t
WHERE t.LOAD_DATE > some_date;
```

Note:  This fixes the syntax (which you oversimplified by leaving out the `OVER` clause).  And removes the `1, NULL`, because those are the default values for those parameters.

Comment: yeah I missed the over by clause.. This will work, but I would like to know if its possible to avoid reading the whole table..  The inline query t reads the whole table

Comment: @Leo Put another `WHERE` filter on the inside limiting it to the previous day

Comment: the thing is that its not sure if we will have data for all days.. if some_date is June 25th, and we don't have records for June 23 & 24, then the previous value should be be June 22nd..

Answer (score 0):

You could try altering your WHERE clause in 2 ways:

1. Add equivalence to the date comparisons, i.e. '>=' instead of '>'
2. Add `WHERE` [VALUE] IS NOT NULL to the conditions